# Passing a file as a Commandline argument in Java

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a program in Java to run pdfgrep in commandline on a given file, but I'm having trouble getting it to execute.

I've written the following code:

```
public class PDFGrepCall {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    PDFGrepCall obj = new PDFGrepCall();

    String searchterm = "git";
    String filename = "~/Documents/COMP2100/03git.slides.pdf";
    String newsearch = "'"+searchterm+"'";
    String command="pdfgrep -c "+newsearch+" "+filename;
    System.out.println(command);

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;

    p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    p.waitFor();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
         output.append(line+"\n");
         }

    System.out.println(output.toString());

    }
```

This should print the command I've written, and on a new line print the results of the command (in this case, the number 57). However, when I run it the program does not give me the results of the command, just prints a newline after the command and terminates.

I can confirm that the command itself outside of java works just fine and that the file exists in the location given.

Have I missed something about passing file arguments to commandline functions from Java? What should I be doing to execute this task correctly?

EDIT: Solved below. It should be done correctly with a processbuilder and by changing the directory to home rather than using "~".

Comment: Check the `Process` error stream.

Comment: @g.grinovski can you get the errors from`BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));`?

Comment: Added the line and a printing code to it, I still get the same result.

Comment: Take `p.waitFor();` and move after you have finished reading the output.  You will also need to read the error stream as well, I think you will find that it can't process the `~` directive.  Use `ProcessBuilder` as it allows you to redirect the error stream to the `InputStream`

Comment: I moved p.waitFor(); to afterwards and that didn't change anything. Trying to read the error message gives me no results either. Have I written my reader wrong?

Comment: @g.grinovski I did a test using `ls ~`, it I got an error saying it couldn't find the directory `~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find that the `~` isn't been interrupted correctly (it's been consider as a literal and not expanded by the exec function)

For example, if I use something like...

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "~");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = p.getInputStream();
            int in = -1;
            while ((in = is.read()) >= 0) {
                System.out.print((char) in);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exited with " + p.waitFor());
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It outputs:

```
ls: cannot access ~: No such file or directory
Exited with 2
```

But if I change it to

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
```

it works fine.

If you need the user home directory, then you're going to need to interrupt it yourself, using `System.getProperty("user.home")`, for example

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

I would also, highly, recommend the use of `ProcessBuilder`, it allows you to redirect the error stream to (among other places) the `InputStream`, which will make life a LOT easier and change the "working" directory from which the process is executed, it also handles arguments with spaces better, which means you could do something like...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```

And get the same result as before

## Further Testing...

Not having `pdfgrep` installed, I thought I might try `grep`

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-i", "banana", "~/Test.txt");
```

which resulted in

```
grep: ~/Test.txt: No such file or directory
Exited with 2
```

(and yes, `Test.txt` is in the home directory)

When I changed it to

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-i", "banana", "Test.txt");
pb.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```

it resulted in

```
ï»¿Bananas are yellow
Exited with 0
```

Comment: I changed it so that I run system.getProperty("user.home") beforehand and add the results of that onto the string in place of the "~", and that didn't work. The command run with the results of getProperty outside Java returns the same result.
Haven't tried using processbuilder yet. Could that change the results of the function?

Comment: It's possible as they execute through different OS functions.  I did further testing using `grep` and it failed when the path was using `~`

Comment: Oh and will I thing about it, you should also print the result of `p.waitFor();`, normally `0` means success

Comment: I tried rewriting it using a processbuilder and it worked, thank you for the help!